# The "standard map" and Jupiter's red spot

Tags: fluid-dynamics, chaotic-systems

Has there been an attempt to "explain" Jupiter's Red Spot via 
what is known as the *[standard map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_map)*
in chaos theory?
I cannot be the first to notice the visual similarities...

---

[image: StandardMap]

      

<sup>Orbits of the Standard Map
$(x, y) \to (x + y, y - 0.971635 \sin (2px)/2p)$.
Image from [this link](http://ckw.phys.ncku.edu.tw/public/pub/Notes/NonlinearPhysics/Web/Chaos/ChaosHypertext/hypertextbook.com/chaos/43.html).</sup>

---

[image: RedSpot]

      

<sup>Jupiter's Red Spot. Image from [this website](http://www.davidreneke.com/why-jupiters-great-red-spot-hasnt-disappeared/#).</sup>

---

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is on topic here since I'm not sure what it has to do with computational science. If you want to ask more specifically about any connections between the physics of the two systems this might be a good question for [Physics.StackExchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com) but I'd suggest editing to make your question more specifically about the physics in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many systems that exhibit (quasi-)periodic orbits surrounded by chaos without much (or any) similarities in the underlying physics. Dynamical systems theory is full of examples. To list a few:

1. The Standard Map is a 2+1 dimensional (2 space and 1 time) system that originates from the physics of a kicked rotator.
2. Arnold-Beltrami-Childress (ABC) flow is a 3 dimensional system representing a spatially periodic steady-state solution of Euler's equations for inviscid fluid motion.
   <sub>Image from [Wolfram](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/poincare-sections.html)</sub>
   [image: Poincare Section for ABC Flow]
3. A periodic double gyre flow. This is a 2+1 dimensional system that is qualitatively similar to some ocean gyres, but is not based on any underlying physical model.
   <sub>Image from [this PDF presentation](http://www.birs.ca/workshops/2013/13w5089/files/rowley_banff.pdf)</sub>
   [image: Double Gyre Poincare Section]

I doubt there is any real connection here aside from some similarities in the Lagrangian dynamics of the system. Examining the Lagrangian dynamics of a system may give many insights into transport and Lagrangian behavior, but typically gives little insight into the physics that give rise to the system in the first place. I see no reason to expect any correspondance between a 3d time-depended fluid dynamical system in a rotating reference frame (Jupiter's red spot) and a simple time-dependent kicked rotator.

Answer (score 2):

This question is of course slightly off-topic here, but in the interest of general education, it may be worth answering it anyway:

Just because two things look similar does not imply that the underlying causes are related. In particular, it is worth pointing out that the picture of the standard map you show actually shows a cross-section of a three-dimensional process (two space and one time dimensions) and only shows points where a line crosses the section. On the other hand, the picture of Jupiter shows certain aspects of fluid flow in a three-dimensional space at a fixed time instant, projected onto a 2d camera observer. In other words, the pictures show entirely different things.

If you plotted the standard map not as a Poincare section but as lines in 3d space, and Jupiters red spot as a vector plot or flowlines in Jupiter's 3d atmosphere, the two pictures would look completely different. Your observation is, in other words, just another example of "correlation is not causation".